# Javascript group URLs by domain and directory

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I group the URLs from a sorted list by domain and directory?

- If two URLs have the same directory (just the first one after domain), then they should be grouped in an array;
- Those URLs whose first directory is different, but have the same domain, should be grouped in an array;

For example, the URLs from this list:

```
var url_list = ["https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/f2e61d9df/?lid=115",
"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=5",
"https://www.facebook.com/tr/a/?id=228037074239568",
"https://www.facebook.com/tr/b/?ev=ViewContent",
"http://www.marvel.com/abc?f=33",
"http://www.marvel.com/games?a=11",
"http://www.marvel.com/games?z=22",
"http://www.marvel.com/videos"]
```

Should be grouped as follows:

```
var group_url = [
    ["https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/f2e61d9df/?lid=115","https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=5",],
    ["https://www.facebook.com/tr/a/?id=228037074239568","https://www.facebook.com/tr/b/?ev=ViewContent"],
    ["http://www.marvel.com/abc?f=33","http://www.marvel.com/videos"],
    ["http://www.marvel.com/games?a=11","http://www.marvel.com/games?z=22"]
]
```

I wrote some code but only managed to group the URLs by domain:

```js
var group_url = [];
var count = 0;
var url_list = ["https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/f2e61d9df/?lid=115",
  "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=5",
  "https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=228037074239568",
  "https://www.facebook.com/tr/?ev=ViewContent",
  "http://www.marvel.com/abc?f=33",
  "http://www.marvel.com/games?a=11",
  "http://www.marvel.com/games?z=22",
  "http://www.marvel.com/videos"]
      
for(i = 0; i < url_list.length; i++) {
  if(url_list[i] != "") {
    var current = url_list[i].replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "");
    var check = current.substr(0, current.indexOf('/'));
    group_url.push([])
    for(var j = i; j < url_list.length; j++) {
      var add_url = url_list[j];
      if(add_url.indexOf(check) != -1) {
        group_url[count].push(add_url);
        url_list[j] = "";
      }
      else {
        break;
      }
    }
    count += 1;
  }
}
     
console.log(JSON.stringify(group_url));
```

Comment: You are giving rules for what URLs should be in the same group, but there are no rules when they should not be in the same group. As I read it now, putting them all in one group would satisfy the 2 conditions.

Comment: The URLs should not be in the same group when the domain is different, as you can see in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to group the URLs by domain+dir, but if they end up being alone in their group, to then regroup those by domain only.

For that you can use this script (ES5):

```js
var url_list = ["https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/f2e61d9df/?lid=115",
"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=5",
"https://www.facebook.com/tr/a/?id=228037074239568",
"https://www.facebook.com/tr/b/?ev=ViewContent",
"http://www.marvel.com/abc?f=33",
"http://www.marvel.com/games?a=11",
"http://www.marvel.com/games?z=22",
"http://www.marvel.com/videos"];

// Group the URLs, keyed by domain+dir
var hash = url_list.reduce(function (hash, url) {
    // ignore protocol, and extract domain and first dir:
    var domAndDir = url.replace(/^.*?:\/\//, '').match(/^.*?\..*?\/[^\/?#]*/)[0];
    hash[domAndDir] = (hash[domAndDir] || []).concat(url);
    return hash;
}, {});

// Regroup URLs by domain only, when they are alone for their domain+dir
Object.keys(hash).forEach(function (domAndDir) {
    if (hash[domAndDir].length == 1) {
        var domain = domAndDir.match(/.*\//)[0];
        hash[domain] = (hash[domain] || []).concat(hash[domAndDir]);
        delete hash[domAndDir];
    }
});
// Convert hash to array
var result = Object.keys(hash).map(function(key) {
    return hash[key];
});

// Output result
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

NB: I did not use ES6 as you mentioned ES5 in comments, but consider using ES6 `Map` for such a hash, which is better suited for the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
urllistextended=url_list.map(function(el){return el.split("://")[1].split("/");});//remove protocol, split by /

var obj={};
for(var index in urllistextended){
var el=urllistextended[index];
    obj[el[0]]=obj[el[0]]||{};
    obj[el[0]][el[1]]=obj[el[0]][el[1]]||[];
    obj[el[0]][el[1]].push(url_list[index]);
 }
```

Use like this:

```
obj["www.facebook.com"];//{plugins:[],tr:[]}
obj["www.facebook.com"]["tr"];//[url1,url2]
```

http://jsbin.com/qacasexowi/edit?console enter "result"

Comment: Can you please change your code to Javascript ES5 ?

Comment: Thank you, but the result is different than the example I provided in the question example

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the excellent URI.js library which offers great ways to parse, query and manipulate URLs: http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/

For example to work with the path (what you are referring to as directory) you could easily do the following (taken straight from the api docs):

```
var uri = new URI("http://example.org/foo/hello.html");
// get pathname
uri.pathname(); // returns string "/foo/hello.html"
// set pathname
uri.pathname("/foo/hello.html"); // returns the URI instance for chaining

// will encode for you
uri.pathname("/hello world/");
uri.pathname() === "/hello%20world/";
// will decode for you
uri.pathname(true) === "/hello world/";

// will return empty string for empty paths, but:
URI("").path() === "";
URI("/").path() === "/";
URI("http://example.org").path() === "/";
```

The rest should be easy going.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an object and group by domain and by the first string after the domain. Then iterate the tree and reduce it to the wanted structure.

This solution works with unsorted data.

```js
var url_list = ["https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/f2e61d9df/?lid=115", "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=5", "https://www.facebook.com/tr/a/?id=228037074239568", "https://www.facebook.com/tr/b/?ev=ViewContent", "http://www.marvel.com/abc?f=33", "http://www.marvel.com/games?a=11", "http://www.marvel.com/games?z=22", "http://www.marvel.com/videos"],
    temp = [],
    result;

url_list.forEach(function (a) {
    var m = a.match(/.*?:\/\/([^\/]+)\/?([^\/?]+)?/);
    m.shift();
    m.reduce(function (r, b) {
        if (!r[b]) {
            r[b] = { _: [] };
            r._.push({ name: b, children: r[b]._ });
        }
        return r[b];
    }, this)._.push(a);
}, { _: temp });

result = temp.reduce(function (r, a) {
    var top = [],
        parts = [];

    a.children.forEach(function (b) {
        if (b.children.length === 1) {
            top.push(b.children[0]);
        } else {
            parts.push(b.children);
        }
    });
    return top.length ? r.concat([top], parts) : r.concat(parts);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you need:

```js
var url_list = ["https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/f2e61d9df/?lid=115",
"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=5",
"https://www.facebook.com/tr/a/?id=228037074239568",
"https://www.facebook.com/tr/b/?ev=ViewContent",
"http://www.marvel.com/abc?f=33",
"http://www.marvel.com/games?a=11",
"http://www.marvel.com/games?z=22",
"http://www.marvel.com/videos"];

var folderGroups = {};
for (var i = 0; i < url_list.length; i++) {

  var myRegexp = /.*\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/\?]+/g;
  var match = myRegexp.exec(url_list[i]);
  var keyForUrl = match[0];
  if (folderGroups[keyForUrl] == null) {
    folderGroups[keyForUrl] = [];
  }
  folderGroups[keyForUrl].push(url_list[i]);
}

var toRemove = [];
Object.keys(folderGroups).forEach(function(key,index) {
    if (folderGroups[key].length == 1) {
      toRemove.push(key);
    }
});
for (var i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
  delete folderGroups[toRemove[i]];
}

//console.log(folderGroups);

var domainGroups = {};
for (var i = 0; i < url_list.length; i++) {
 //Check if collected previously
  var myRegexpPrev = /.*\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/\?]+/g;
  var matchPrev = myRegexpPrev.exec(url_list[i]);
  var checkIfPrevSelected = matchPrev[0];
  debugger;
  if (folderGroups[checkIfPrevSelected] != null) {
    continue;
  }
  //Get for domain group
  var myRegexp = /.*\/\/[^\/]+/g;
  var match = myRegexp.exec(url_list[i]);
  var keyForUrl = match[0];
  if (domainGroups[keyForUrl] == null) {
    domainGroups[keyForUrl] = [];
  }
  domainGroups[keyForUrl].push(url_list[i]);
}

//console.log(domainGroups);

var finalResult = {};
$.extend(finalResult, folderGroups, domainGroups);
console.log(Object.values(finalResult));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```