# How can I group similar URLs (with subdomain) in an array using JavaScript (or any of its libraries)

Tags: javascript

I have to convert this

```
['https://150sec.com/story-of-enigma'
,'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hiccups'
,'http://10.1.4.128:3000/#/campaigns/new'
,'http://localhost:3000/'
,'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yydZbVoCbn0&t=170s'
,'https://150sec.com/how-to-play-a-paino/'
,'https://www.worldfree4u.lol/mahabharat-1988'
,'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello+world'
,'http://nthloop.github.io/bowerbird/'
,'https://pages.github.com/'
,'https://github.com/'
,'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbydZb23432t=170s'
,'http://localhost:2000/']
```

into

```
[
['https://150sec.com/story-of-enigma',
'https://150sec.com/how-to-play-a-paino/'],

['https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hiccups',
'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello+world'],

['http://10.1.4.128:3000/#/campaigns/new'],

['http://localhost:3000/'],

['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yydZbVoCbn0&t=170s',
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbydZb23432t=170s'],

['https://www.worldfree4u.lol/mahabharat-1988'],

['http://nthloop.github.io/bowerbird/',
'https://pages.github.com/',
'https://github.com/']
]
```

I know, it awkward to directly ask for a solution, but I have tried a lot of things [like this](https://github.com/hiddentao/fast-levenshtein).

Comment: Why is `github.io` in the same array as `github.com`?

Comment: Do you have some code to show us? :)

Comment: This might get you in the right track: https://jsfiddle.net/3m2u6hq1/

Comment: @Andreas because both of them are of github!

Comment: you could have a look here: [Javascript group URLs by domain and directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328197/javascript-group-urls-by-domain-and-directory)

Comment: So the requirement is to group by hostname only, ignoring sub- and top-level domains - which is contrary to the requirement in the title

Comment: Why is "http://localhost:2000/" not included at expected result?

Comment: @Andreas is right, there is no connection between the domains `github.io` and `github.com`. Either you remove the domain-specific part, or have a whitelist. You'd have to have a valid list of "domain parts" to remove too, since many country-specific domains use two base levels (`.co.uk` and not just one `.fm`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to group them only by the hostname (incl. port) without the domain, you need to extract it first. Rest of it it pretty straightforward.

```js
const inputs = ['https://150sec.com/story-of-enigma', 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hiccups', 'http://10.1.4.128:3000/#/campaigns/new', 'http://localhost:3000/', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yydZbVoCbn0&t=170s', 'https://150sec.com/how-to-play-a-paino/', 'https://www.worldfree4u.lol/mahabharat-1988', 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello+world', 'http://nthloop.github.io/bowerbird/', 'https://pages.github.com/', 'https://github.com/', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbydZb23432t=170s', 'http://localhost:2000/'];

const results = inputs.reduce((a, x) => {
  const hostparts = new URL(x).host.split('.');
  let host;
  if (hostparts.length < 3) {
    host= hostparts.shift();
  } else {
    host= hostparts.slice(1, hostparts.length - 1);
  }

  if (a[host]) {
    a[host].push(x);
  } else {
    a[host] = [x];
  }
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(results));
```

Keep in mind that this solution is for modern browsers only.

Comment: @Zafta What is with _localhost_? There are two entries in different arrays. The accepted solution doesn't fit with the original requirement nor with the actual requirement...

Comment: @Andreas Why do you think it does not fit? It does excactly what Op wanted.

Comment: Why would `localhost:2000` be in a different array than `localhost:3000`?

Comment: @Andreas I don't know, but that *is* what Op wanted.

Comment: This "special" case is not shown in the expected output and doesn't fit your own assumption: _"group them **only by the hostname**"_

Comment: @Andreas You're right for both but `"http://localhost:2000/"` was clealy just forgotten. The text is not that right, good point. Will change it in a few mins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158149/discussion-between-werner-and-andreas).

Answer (score 1):

This should put you on the right track, it uses

- [array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b)
- [array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [string.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

```js
const data = ['https://150sec.com/story-of-enigma','https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hiccups','http://10.1.4.128:3000/#/campaigns/new','http://localhost:3000/','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yydZbVoCbn0&t=170s','https://150sec.com/how-to-play-a-paino/','https://www.worldfree4u.lol/mahabharat-1988','https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello+world','http://nthloop.github.io/bowerbird/','https://pages.github.com/','https://github.com/','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbydZb23432t=170s','http://localhost:2000/'];

let result = data.reduce((group, current) => {
  if (group.length === 0) {
    group.push([current])
    return group;
  }
  
  let url = new URL(current);
  let index = group.findIndex(val => {
    let test = val.find(local => (local.includes(url.host)));
    if (test === undefined) { return false }
    return true;
  });
  
  if (index < 0) { return [ ...group, [current] ] }
  group[index].push(current);
  return group;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: github and github pages are separate things, with separate domains, but i'm sure you could apply the same logic to a second reducer to merge on that other criteria.

Comment: I thought so too, but... _"@Andreas because both of them are of github!"_ And I've only asked about the different top-level domains and not about the different sub domains...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()`, `.filter()`, `URL()` and `RegExp` to check the `.origin` of the current URL

```
let res = urls.map(url => 
            urls.filter(curr => 
              new RegExp(newURL(url).origin.split(/http:|https:|\/|\.\w+$/)
             .filter(Boolean).join("|"))
             .test(new URL(curr).origin))
          );
```